# Can I create new variable with for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm creating new variables for classes, can I do something like this?

`for i in range(8): s{i} = card(i, "hearth") #card is class`

Or is there some alternative? It would be very helpful if I could do it

I want this output

`s0 = card(O, "hearth") s1 = card(1, "hearth") #etc..`

Comment: [It has been drawn already](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/spxfi3/loooopss/), why asking it in text-form again.

Comment: Rather than a variable name, make the name a (str) key in a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Make a list:

```
s = [card(i, "hearth") for i in range(8)]
```

Now you have `s[0]`, `s[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically name variables in a loop. I would add them to a list instead:

```
card_list = [card(i, "hearth") for i in range(8)]
```

So you can then access them with the index.